# I have 4 monitors - Can I group 3 as one, and leave the fourth unaffected?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have Windows 7 and GeForce GTX 960. I also have four monitors, 3 connected through Display port and one through DVI (the main screen). I am running a driving simulator which needs 3 monitors (the ones connected through Display port). They all have identical resolutions (1680x1050). Is it possible to create one screen with resolution 5040x1050, by merging the 3 monitors, and leave the 4th one unaffected? This setup was there when I inherited the system, but somehow I messed it up... The feature called Surround configuration in NVIDIA control panel does not seem to do the trick, since it only allows all four to be grouped together.

Thanks!

Comment: I used to have a third-party utility that did this. I can't think what it was called now, but you may be able to find it with some searching.

Comment: I tried UltraMon, which has a setting called "detached" for one screen, but no luck. Will look for other ones.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was Ultramon. Does the driving simulator not support the three monitors as they are? You say it "needs" three monitors, so surely that means it supports three individual monitors without having to trick it into thinking they are one monitor.

Comment: It's an old peace of software, designed to work for an older version of NVIDIA control panel. In its manual it gives instructions on how to set it up for the old version, where it says that two monitors are required, one for the controller and one for the simulator. Since the current system has four instead of two, my best guess was to merge the three monitors into one. What it does now is that it displays the simulator on the three monitors and the controller's view on the fourth, but the simulator is off sync, leaving some screen space empty...

Comment: Have you tried using the settings on the monitor to adjust the picture? The auto button might automatically align it, if not you could try it manually.